# Apply styling/color to the first element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have the following code displaying a breacrumb in React. I want to add some style or a link to the first element only. How to do so ?

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', breadcrumb: 'Dashboard'},
  { path: '/patients', breadcrumb: 'Patients' },
  { path: '/add', breadcrumb: 'Creation' },
];

const Breadcrumbs = withBreadcrumbs(routes, { disableDefaults: true })(({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {breadcrumbs.map(({ breadcrumb }, index) => {
      return (
         <span>
          {index !== 0 && <span> •</span>}  {breadcrumb}
        </span> 
      );
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
));
```

Comment: Seems like easiest thing is CSS rule

Comment: Like applying it to index==0 ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should always try the best to move `if statement` outside of the loop for this kind of requirements.

```
const Breadcrumbs = withBreadcrumbs(routes, { disableDefaults: true })(({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <span className='special-style'>{breadcrumbs[0]}</span> // first element and applys special css classes or styles
    {breadcrumbs.slice(1).map(({ breadcrumb }, index) => {  // loop the rest of elements=breadcrumbs.slice(1)
      return (
         <span key={index}>
          {<span> •</span>}  {breadcrumb}
        </span> 
      );
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
))
```

Comment: Logically I understood what you meant. Although I have this error now `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {match, location, key, breadcrumb}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

Comment: let `Array.map` returns `<span key={index}>`

Comment: Yes I was missing that one. Thanks.